# How to transform a dataframe into a heatmap format?

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe:

```
Name <- c("Apple", "Banana", "Milk")
black <- c(1, 2, 3)
white <- c(10, 5, 999)
df <- data.frame(Name, black, white)
print (df)
```

That results in:

```
    Name black white
1  Apple     1    10
2 Banana     2     5
3   Milk     3   999
```

I would like to transform it as follows:

```
    X     Y    Z  
1 black Apple  1
2 white Apple  10
3 black Banana 2
4 white Banana 5
5 black Milk   3
6 white Milk   999
```

Comment: This can be done in tidyr package using function pivot_longer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
library(tidyr)
long_df <- df |> pivot_longer(cols = c('black', 'white'), names_to = "X", values_to = "Z")
```

Slightly reorganised to keep the "Name" column name.

| Name | X | Z |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | black | 1 |
| Apple | white | 10 |
| Banana | black | 2 |
| Banana | white | 5 |
| Milk | black | 3 |
| Milk | white | 999 |

To produce a heatmap:

```
library(ggplot2)
long_df |> ggplot(aes(Name, X, fill = Z)) + geom_tile()
```

which is very skewed by the white milk value of 999.

Answer (score 0):

This is a short article where the author shows a nice way to generate heatmaps from dataframes, it will only take you two minutes.

https://datascientyst.com/display-pandas-dataframe-heatmap/

Comment: Thanks but I need to do it in R